# Woocommerce Новый метод доставки

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Здравствуйте.

С [этой страницы](http://www.mint-studio.net/web-development/wordpress/add-new-method-delivery-woocommerce.html) создал плагин нового метода доставки.

В настройках Woocommerce появилась новая вкладка. Однако в зонах доставки при Добавлении нового метода доставки новый метод отсутствует.  Есть только 3 стандартных.

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    function nova_poshta() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Nova_Poshta' ) ) {
            class WC_Nova_Poshta extends WC_Shipping_Method {
                public function __construct() {
                    $this->id = 'nova-poshta';
                    $this->method_title = __( 'Новая почта' ); // Title shown in admin
                    $this->method_description = __( 'Новая почта' );

                    $this->enabled = "yes";
                    $this->title = "Новая почта";

                    $this->init();
                }

                function init() {
                    $this->init_form_fields();
                    $this->init_settings();

                    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
                }

                public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
                    $rate = array(
                        'id' => $this->id,
                        'label' => $this->title,
                        'cost' => '0',
                        'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
                    );

                    $this->add_rate( $rate );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'nova_poshta' );

    function add_nova_poshta( $methods ) {
        $methods[] = 'WC_Nova_Poshta';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_nova_poshta' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант использовать бесплатный плагин Flexible Shipping